# Very high CPU usage when playing web videos (Ubuntu 16.04.3)

Tags: ubuntu, cpu, firefox, video, youtube

I have just set up a new laptop - Dell XPS13 running Ubuntu 16.04.3 LTS. I've noticed very high CPU usage when watching web video. From a fresh boot, I start a single Firefox (or Chromium) window, navigate to e.g.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5SfXqTENV_Q

and the video starts playing, and I watch (via htop) the CPU usage for firefox jump to about 90% and stay there.

I've reproduced this on both Firefox and Chromium, and on youtube, BBC iplayer and vimeo.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Did you watch HD video?

Comment: This is with 1080p video, but I get the same result when I switch down to 480.

Comment: Maybe it can be either bug on Firefox or Chromium, bug at Ubuntu system itself, or the video you're watching is too "heavy"